# Different AppDomain in WebRole and HttpHandler

Tags: .net, azure

I have a web project (asp.net mvc) deployed as a web role in windows azure. For the web role i have a WebRole class inheriting from RoleEntryPoint. I have overridden the OnStart() Method to initialize some static classes.

In a RequestHandler (IHttpHandler) of the same project I use these static classes, but they are not initialized - i have to initialize them in the Global.asax again. I think they are in different application domains.

I have not tested this behavior in the real azure environment, only in the emulator.

Is there a way to fix this? I need the static class to share data between the WebRole class and the request handlers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The WebRole.cs runs in a different process than your actual web application (explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx)):

[image]

If you want your web application to use static classes you will need to use the Global.asax. If you don't want to duplicate code consider storing the static properties in a different class and have them initialized in both the WebRole.cs and Global.asax, like this:

```
public static class MyStaticThingie
{
    public static string XmlContentThingie { get; private set; }
    public static Container IoCContainer { get; private set; }

    public static void Init()
    {
        IoCContainer = ...;
        XmlContentThingie = File.ReadAllText("Somefile.xml");
    }
}

public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        MyStaticThingie.Init();

        var something = MyStaticThingie.IoCContainer.GetSomething();
        something.DoSomething();

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyStaticThingie.Init();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. But because they run in different AppDomains, I have to share the common data in a different way. I use the file system now.

Comment: You can also use Windows Azure Caching to share the data.